# Marketing Cloud Connector Individual Email Results Cleanup

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have over 2 million records stored in my Individual Email Results object (created by Marketing Cloud Connector) which I would like to remove. I have tried using the Tracking Data Cleanup Tool in the Switchboard but it only returns 3 records, when I press "Delete All" it only deletes those three records it mentioned.

Can I simply wipe out the data using Data Loader (extract and then delete)?

and secondly why weren't the rest of my records be deleted?

(The only thing I can think of that may affect this is that I have upgrade the connector twice this year)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the records via Data Loader is totally fine, have done it for several orgs in the past. You'll only need the individual record ID's in the CSV file to process, but be prepared for a long processing time.

I would advise splitting up the 2M records to 10x files containing 200K records each and just go through these one by one. You will also need to mind your SF org API limits per 24h.

As for the other question I have no comment, if your current MC package is up to date and you haven't configured any custom additions on top then it should've worked. I would open up a support case with MC support to get that cleared up.

Comment: Can you confirm which objects are safe to delete? There are a number of them related to Marketing Cloud so I don't wan't to remove anything vital to the package to run, just the tracking records.

Comment: I hope you meant which records. Anyway, if I recall it correctly it was called et4ae5__IndividualEmailResult__c. 

Easiest way is to create a Salesforce Report for Individual Email Results and export only the record ID's for Data Loader.

Comment: Sorry yes I meant records in which objects are safe to delete from, I can see the following: Individual Email Results, Individual Link Level Details, Aggregate Link Level Details.

Comment: From these it's up to you which you are going to remove. The Individual Link Level Details and Aggregated Link Level Details are related to the Individual Email Results, on how your subscribers behaved with any of the links/CTA's on the specific Email. Personally if I were to remove all Individual Email Results I would also clean up both Link Level Details.

Comment: Is there a way to disable it ? I mean a way to not receive Individual Email Results in ServiceCloud

Comment: Yes. Go to Marketing Cloud Connector settings in Salesforce and turn off the "Individual Level Tracking" in the Tracking section.

Comment: I just did it, however we are still receiving bulk jobs from it. But when we watch the ids, these are old records(3,2,1 months ago). It's not logic. Plus we already have bulk jobs and we are limited to 10,000 jobs. Many criticial ETL jobs have failed because of it.

Comment: @Rain I don't see individual Marketing cloud Connect settings as of today, but I do see where I can put the individual object back to 'in development' status. WIll that accomplish the same task as disabling the storing of the object? I couldn't find anywhere else, other than this thread, that describes disabling the storage functionality.